# Is it possible to dual boot Ubuntu on 2016 macbook pro without USB?

Tags: system-installation, mac

I would like to install ubuntu on my 2016 macbook pro. I understand that it is easy to create an installer using a flashdrive however I do not have access to one at this time. Is there any possible way I can go ahead and install ubuntu without one?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, yes, you can install without a USB stick technically. I do not have a same macintosh laptop and not sure this will work. First, shrink the partition for enough to make an iso installer 2-3 GB, then use dd command from Mac OS to build an installer partition then boot it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Download the ISO file for the version of your choice at https://ubuntu.com/download or for a 'flavour' with a different Desktop Environment, download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours .

The ISO file you use to create a LiveDVD should be checked for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 .

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-macos#0 shows how to create an Ubuntu LiveDVD in MacOS.

Further information may be found at https://www.lifewire.com/dual-boot-linux-and-mac-os-4125733

Once you make a LiveDVD, install it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0 . When you reach [6. Allocate drive space](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#5), choose Something Else and divide the existing disk space between MacOS and Ubuntu.